# (Android)How to access google assistant resources such as asking about the weather via dialogflow

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

The DialogFlow can custome intent, but I want to add more function in my android app, such as weather, alarm or more. Then the google assistant Can satisfy me, but I don't know how to implement it, I can't find the demo or interface for java, who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to embed GA to an Android App or have a complete independent GA app that you can invoke on your Android Device.

For the embedding stuff probably following links may help you
building a [gRPC library](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-other-platforms/integrate) and [getting started](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/android.html) with gRPC for Android.

For the second case, here is what I would do:
1. Create different intents in my Dialogflow agent - one to ask weather info, one for setting alarm, etc.
2. Create a [webhook](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app)
3. In the code, based on the identified intent, do your stuff - if the weather is identified, get info from weather services, if the alarm is identified, set the alarm.

Hope, this helps you.